# How to make circle on spesific places with mouse pos in canvas grid

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, html5-canvas

so I am trying to make this Japanese game called GO and I need to place circles in the edges like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7Uam.jpg). I've made the grid now need to place the circles in there. I 'v tried different things like using the arc in canvas with mouse position and placing it but it isn't working something else I tried is to make an array that checks where the lines cross but it still didn't do anything. I'm not sure what's wrong so hope you guys could help me find a way to place the circles on the board every time I click the mouse. I've deleted the things that didn't work and this is my code now:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
//canvas.style.border = "1px solid black"
let w = ctx.canvas.width
let h = ctx.canvas.height


goBoard = []
goCheckBoard = []

function drawGrid(w, h) {

    for (x = 0; x <= w; x += 40) {
        for (y = 0; y <= h; y += 40) {
            ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
            ctx.lineTo(x, h);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.moveTo(0, y);
            ctx.lineTo(w, y);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }
}

drawGrid(400, 400)
```

this just makes the grid

one example is this:

```
mouseClicked = function () {
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black"
    ctx.ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
    ctx.stroke()
};
```

another:

```
if (mouseIsPressed) {
    ellipse(200, 200, 180, 180);
}
```

im not sure that is the correct way to do it

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```js
function rtn(n, r){
    return Math.round(n/r)*r;
}
canvas.onclick = function(event){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(rtn(event.clientX, 40), rtn(event.clientY, 40), 180, 180, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fill();
};
```

ClientX and ClientY have documentation [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_mouseevent.asp)

Comment: it says ellipse is not defined.

Comment: Sorry. I'm used to using p5.js. It uses that. I'll fix that real quick.